# How to undo cropping "artboard" in Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop

After I've used the Cropping Tool (without Delete Cropped Pixels selected), how do I get back to the original image with absolutely no cropping ratios selected.  I click on and off to see the original and the previously cropped area, but there's no way to just see the original anymore. It always pops a dialog, "do you want to crop the image?", and it doesn't matter if I click yes or no it goes to the previously cropped area.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to undo a cropped selection, use CTRL/CMD + Z to undo.

If you want to clear any preset ratio settings, just click the "Clear" button.

[image: clear ratio button]

You can also select the drop down menu to select different crop presets including the original image ratio.

[image: Original ratio presets]

If you want to find the width and height of the original image. You can CTRL/CMD + Left Click on the thumbnail of the layer. Then go to "Info" panel to view the width and height.

[image: width and height info]

If all else fails, you can enlarge the canvas to the image you want and then crop holding shift.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. When I do Original Ratio, yes, it shows the whole image, but when I select something else, it prompts, "crop the image"? Yes & No: actually crop it to the previous crop ratio. Your last suggestion works. But it still doesn't make sense to me that I need to crop it to uncrop it.  What I'm trying to determine is if there's a way to uncrop an image, i.e., not be forced to use any dimensions etc., i.e., restore it to its original state without the crop overlay forcing me to crop the image.  It would make sense this is possible b/c it's a non-destructive crop.

Comment: @JoeFletcher I am not really certain on what you're trying to achieve. If you want the original canvas size and know the width and height of the image, you can go to Image -> Canvas Size and change the size to that of the image. If you're using the crop tool you either have to make the crop (whether it is larger or smaller) or right click and cancel. If you select another tool while cropping, it will ask you whether or not you want to complete the crop action.

Comment: Thanks, you're comment hinted at what I needed: Image -> Reveal All. After I've cropped an image, I couldn't find a way to work on the original without re-cropping back out, which requires several (wasted) steps, and undoes my crop layout position unnecessarily. All I needed was Reveal All.